# -bash: rabbitmq-server: command not found

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, rabbitmq

Trying to start my rabbitmq server, but I get this error. I've followed all of the instructions on [how to install it](http://www.marinamele.com/2014/02/how-to-install-celery-on-django-and.html). The `rabbitmq-server` file lives inside `/usr/local/sbin`. So I change directory to `sbin`, and write `rabbitmq-server` in my terminal but it shows the error `-bash: rabbitmq-server: command not found`. I've already added the following line: `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH` at the bottom of my `bash_profile`, as per instructions. Any idea why it isn't working?

Comment: have you run `source bash_profile` after adding path in your `bash_profile` ?

Comment: Did you try to run: "source bash_profile" ? After adding any changes to that file, this command is required.

Comment: That was the problem, now it's working. Thanks!

Comment: It reloads .bash_profile from the command line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try this,

Navigate to the path 'RabbitMQ Server \rabbitmq_server-VERSION\sbin' then follow below steps,

1. Run the command 'rabbitmqctl status'. You will the full status (This is just to check the status).
2. Now run 'rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management'
3. Run the command 'rabbitmqctl stop'
4. Run the command 'rabbitmq-service start'
5. In browser go to localhost:15672

Now You should be able to see RabbitMQ management plugin, it means all services running fine. You can try login with guest as username and password, which is the default one.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer this command:

`brew services run rabbitmq`

I feel it more similar to systemd.

```
brew services command:
Integrates Homebrew formulae with macOS' launchctl manager.

[sudo] brew services list
List all running services for the current user (or root)

[sudo] brew services run formula|--all
Run the service formula without starting at login (or boot).

[sudo] brew services start formula|--all
Start the service formula immediately and register it to launch at login (or boot).

[sudo] brew services stop formula|--all
Stop the service formula immediately and unregister it from launching at login (or boot).

[sudo] brew services restart formula|--all
Stop (if necessary) and start the service immediately and register it to launch at login (or boot).

[sudo] brew services cleanup
Remove all unused services.
```